# Anuglar CLI will not upgrade beyond version 1.6.0

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

According to **npm**, the latest version of `@angular/cli` as of this writing, is `v6.2.5`.

When I run `ng -v`, I get

```
_                      _                 ____ _     ___
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
/ △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
/ ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
|___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/language-service: 5.2.11
@angular-devkit/architect: 0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.8.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35
@angular-devkit/build-webpack: 0.8.5
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.41
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 6.2.5
typescript: 2.7.2
webpack: 4.21.0
```

So I tried upgrading, executing these commands

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

However, when I run **`ng -v`** again, I still get the same output as above!

What isn't `ng` upgrading as expected?

Comment: Tested node version 10.x?

Comment: Do you have a package.json? If so, manually remove your node_modules directory and npm install

Comment: @ngfelixl Node version 8.11.3

Comment: @rrd Yes I have a package.json

Comment: It looks like up are running `ng -v` in a directory of an ng application that uses cli version 1.6.0, which will show the local version being used, and not the global. What do you see if you run `ng -v` in a directory where there is no ng application?

Comment: @R.Richards I was indeed running it from the project folder... but I've since deleted everything and reinstalled so I can't know forsure if that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Github repo for [@angular/cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) defines its package.json for nodejs engine like

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=10.9.0 <11.0.0",
  "yarn": ">=1.9.0 <2.0.0"
}
```

So try install node >=10.9 and <11.0 try again.

Comment: I installed Node 10.12.0 and ng cli still won't install past `1.6.0`

Comment: That's weird, maybe you could try uninstall node, delete npm cache folder, on windows its `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm` and install again?

Comment: Ok will try that